# Train Faster RCNN on Custom Dataset

Tags: python, computer-vision, deep-learning, caffe, object-recognition

I am trying to run `Py-Faster-RCNN` for 2 class problem say, `obj1` and `obj2`.

1. I have stored the data in Pascal format.
2. I also changed the number of output in last layers of the caffe definition to 3 ( i.e. 2 + BG ) and 12 ( 4 * 3 ).
3. For some reasons, I cannot use pretrained model.

Now, I wish to train the `caffe` model from scratch for above mentioned two classes. So, my question is; If I am running the following command,

```
./tools/train_net.py --gpu 0 --imdb voc_2007_trainval --cfg experiments/cfgs/config.yml --solver models/pascal_voc/ZF/faster_rcnn_end2end/solver.prototxt --iter 10000
```

Is it working as per my requirement (or, what I am thinking) i.e. object classification and localization for `obj1` and `obj2`. Or, something else is happening? Because, my AP values are very low (`obj1 = 0.042`; `obj2 = 0.006`) for the model I obtained by running it for 10000 iterations.

Comment: I found tuning SSD detector from scratch much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have arranged your data for `obj1` and `obj2` classes in PASCAL format then you are correctly running the training code.

I assume that you have taken special care in creating the text files which mention about the training and testing samples. Please, see PASCAL setup for reference.